# Using Automapper through a join table in EFCore

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Recipe` and `Item` via a join table called `Ingredient`:

```
 public class Recipe
 {
     public int RecipeId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public ICollection<RecipeInstruction> RecipeInstructions { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
 }

public class Ingredient
{
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}

 public class Item
 {
     public int ItemId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Brand { get; set; }   

     public ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
  }
```

I would like to present the data through this DTO:

```
 public class RecipeForDetailedDto
 {   
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      

    public ICollection<RecipeInstruction> RecipeInstructions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemForDetailedDto> Ingredients { get; set; }
 }
```

Is there a way I can map this relationship to show a list of Ingredient names, which would be the Item Name?

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
CreateMap<Ingredient, ItemForDetailedDto>();
CreateMap<Ingredient,RecipeForDetailedDto>()
    .ForMember(dest=>dest.Name, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Item?.Name));

var result = mapper.Map<ItemDetailedDto>(yourIngredientObject);
```

Comment: The null check is not needed, AM does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this is what worked:

```
    CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientForDetailedDto>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Item.Name))
```

With IngredientForDetailedDto as:

```
 public class IngredientForDetailedDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string QuantityType { get; set; }

    }
```